# sizeof and when a byte is larger than 8 bits?

Tags: c, bit

1. Since `sizeof` is an operator, why can we use `sizeof(something);` like a function call?
2. When is a byte not 8 bits?

> A byte in this context is the same as an unsigned char, and may be larger than 8 bits

And is there a possible that byte is smaller than 8 bits?

Comment: C90, §5.2.4.2.1 requires CHAR_BIT >= 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since sizeof is a operater ,why can we use sizof(something); like a function call ?

Well, `+` is an "operater" (sic!) too, still you can write `(1 + 1)` and `(1) + (1)` and `((1) + 1)`... it's just normal parenthesizing/grouping.

> When byte is not 8 bits?

When you use a platform on which it isn't 8 bits.

> And is there a possible that byte is smaller than 8 bits ?

Not on an architecture that aims to be a conforming C implementation. It can happen, though. Some of the early punch card machines used 6-bit bytes, for example.

Comment: I read the line from Wiki and got confused , hope to know when byte is  larger than 8 bits .

Comment: Some DSP C compilers have bytes with more than 8 bits - this is because the DSP in question does not have byte addressing, so the byte size is set to the basic word size, e.g. 24 bits.

Comment: @LidongGuo What exactly do you mean by "when it is larger than 8 bits"? It is when it is. When you use such an architecture.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do we really have those kind of architecture now ?

Comment: @LidongGuo I haven't personally used one, but I'm sure you will find one the old riders here who have :)

Comment: @H2CO3 The newest cutting edge (mostly non-publicly available) microcontrollers sometimes don't use 8 bit bytes (e.g. 4 or 16) to make the circuits simpler, and hence the chip smaller and cheaper. Often the manufacturer doesn't bother with a C compiler though, so you have to program in ASM right away (which sucks if you're the one who has to program that thing), but plenty of those exist. Mostly I've seen 16 bit access only for small EEPROM units in controllers; or 4-bit for supplemental on-chip modules like LIN-controllers.

Comment: @dialer That seems reasonable. (Honestly, the only uC I've worked with is AVR which is an 8-bit device.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Lucky you! All Atmel chips I've worked with were so nice to program.

Comment: @dialer Yep, it's a pretty friendly platform ;)

Comment: There's nothing ancient about DSPs - you probably have at least one in your cell phone.

Comment: @PaulR Uh, sorry, I don't see where I asserted that?

Comment: When you said: "I haven't personally used one, but I'm sure you will find one the old riders here who have" - I took that to mean that you thought that only systems from long ago had char > 8 bits ?

Comment: @PaulR Ah okay. Fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

Like most operators, `sizeof` can be applied to an expression, which can include parentheses. As far as the parser cares, it's pretty much the same as something like `x * (b + c)`, where `*` applies to `(b + c)`. While you don't see it as often, something like `x + (b)` is also entirely possible.

The standard specifies that `CHAR_MIN` must be no higher than -127 and `CHAR_MAX` must be at least 127. That requires at least 8 bits to represent, so no, a char can't be any smaller than 8 bits.

Comment: When will byte larger than 8 bits  ?

Comment: @LidongGuo: When the implementer decides it should. Given the prevalence of UTF-8, I'm not sure it'll ever become common.

Comment: Making `char` larger than 8 bits has nothing to do with character encodings. It has to do with machines that cannot address or operate on 8-bit units -- usually, DSPs that only have a single-size unit of memory access, typically 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: @R..: It's relevant to the extent that it influences CPU designers about what sizes of items they make addressable. As long as people continue to use 8-bit quantities, most machines will continue to support them. If everybody started to use UTF-16, chances of a machine that worked in 16-bit bytes would be much higher.

Comment: No, it really wouldn't. You still need `CHAR_BIT==8` to support all existing binary data files, network protocols, etc. Text is a very small portion of the issue.

Comment: @R..: Oh, how foolish of me. Obviously that's why all computers still support 5-bit types -- to support 5-bit Baudot codes where needed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: There's a difference between data formats used by 0.0001% of the human population and largely irrelevant to commerce, and ones used by 50% or more of the human population and 100% of world commerce.

Comment: @R..: Yet again you seem to be missing the point (to the point I think it *must* be intentional). Yes, Baudot codes are *now* some minuscule percentage of anything -- but at one time accounted for essentially *all* electronic storage, communication, formats, protocols, etc.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: And you're missing the point that, at that time, electronic storage and communication was an insignificant minority of human information storage and communication.

Comment: @R..: On that, you're just plain wrong (and if you'd ever stopped by a newspaper office, for only one example, in the 1970s or so, you'd know better).

Answer (score 2):

1. > Since sizeof is a operater ,why can we use sizof(something); like a function call ?

   Others answered this, but I'll answer anyway. `~` is an operator, so why can we use `~(a)` instead of `~a`? While fundamentally different, they are still similar in terms of syntax. The exception is that you can do `sizeof(int)`, but that is because of what `sizeof` does, which is expand to a compile-time constant.
2. > When byte is not 8 bits ?
   >
   > > A byte in this context is the same as an unsigned char, and may be larger than 8 bits

   Some platforms have 9-bit bytes. The C standard requires a minimum of 8 bits per char. Currently, many systems use an 8-bit byte, a.k.a. an "octet".

   In a language like Java, `char` is not 8 bits, so an implementation of C could just as easily define it the same way. You just wouldn't be able to access smaller amounts of data using standard C syntax without bit masks and bit shifts or bit-fields because other data types like `short int` are defined in terms of `char`:

   > Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* × **CHAR_BIT** bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes.

   So if `sizeof(short int)` is 2, it will have `2 × CHAR_BIT` bits. If `CHAR_BIT` is 16, a `short int` is a 32-bit integer type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in computer science definition of byte. Which is 8 bits. And C definiton is byte is number of bits that type char has. Since it's almost always the same, it is common that they are treated as equal.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes.
2. Doubtful that you have a machine where a byte is not 8 bits. In any event, sizeof() takes a type. "byte" is not a type. A type is something like "char" "short" "int". In C, the smallest type is a char which is one byte. Perhaps I should say "probably one byte".

Comment: Actually, `sizeof` does not "take a type". It takes an expression, which can look like a cast. But it's better to use `sizeof` on objects, such as `int *nums = malloc(3 * sizeof *nums);` and so on.

Comment: @unwind When you write `sizeof(int)`, isn't the argument of `sizeof` a type? Or is it actually `sizeof <the big nothing cast to int>`?

Comment: sizeof() takes an expression or a type name.