# Reverse bytes for 64-bit value

Tags: c, byte, reverse, swap, endianness

I'm trying to reverse the bytes for a 64 bit address pointer for an assignment and have this code:

```
char swapPtr(char x){
x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
return x;
}
```

But, it just messes everything up. However, a similar function works perfectly for a 64bit long. Is there something different that needs to be done for pointers?

Could the way I'm making the function call be an issue?

For a pointer:

```
*(char*)loc = swapPtr(*(char*)loc);
```

For a long:

```
*loc = swapLong(*loc);
```

Comment: `char` is not the right datatype. It's (usually) one 8bit byte. If you're on a platform with 64bit chars, please mention that.

Comment: yes, it is on the x86_64 architecture

Comment: Then a char is 8 bits. It can't possibly hold a 64bit value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `char x` for a pointer!!!!  A `char` is only a single byte long.

You need at the very least

```
unsigned long int swapPtr(unsigned long int x) {
```

Or better, use the type of the pointer

```
void* swapPtr(void* x) {
```

Quite likely your compiler will complain when you start bit shifting pointers; in that case you're better off explicitly casting your argument to an unsigned 64 bit integer:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t x;
```

Note also that you have to call with the address of a variable, so you call with

```
result = swapLong(&loc);
```

not `*loc` (which looks at the place where `loc` is pointing - the value, not the address).

Complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t swapLong(void *X) {
  uint64_t x = (uint64_t) X;
x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
return x;
}

int main(void) {
  char a;
  printf("the address of a is 0x%016llx\n", (uint64_t)(&a));
  printf("swapping all the bytes gives 0x%016llx\n",(uint64_t)swapLong(&a));
}
```

Output:

```
the address of a is 0x00007fff6b133b1b
swapping all the bytes gives 0x1b3b136bff7f0000
```

**EDIT** you could use something like

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("the address of a is 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", (uint64_t)(&a));
```

where the macro `PRIx64` expands into "the format string you need to print a 64 bit number in hex". It is a little cleaner than the above.

Comment: Just don't use fixed width types for such a task. The appropriate type is `uintptr_t`. In addition you could "`#if UINTPRT_SIZE > UINT32_SIZE`" the part that supposes that the width is 64 bit.

Comment: @jensgustedt thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize there was a `uintptr_t` - should have thought to look. Learning something every day!

Comment: Minor: Consider `printf("0x016" PRIx64, (uint64_t)(&a))` or `printf("0x%016llx\n", (unsigned long long)(&a))` instead of as posted to get the format and integer to match?

Comment: @chux - that would indeed be better. There are several ways this could be improved... Might do so when I am near a computer (rather than phone)

Answer (score 4):

You may also use **_bswap64** intrinsic (which has latency of 2 and a throughput of 0.5 on Skylake Architecture). It is a wrapper for the assembly instruction `bswap r64` so probably the most efficient :

> Reverse the byte order of 64-bit integer a, and store the result in dst. This intrinsic is provided for conversion between little and big endian values.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

uint64_t swapLongIntrinsic(void *X) {
    return __bswap_64((uint64_t) X);
}
```

NB: Don't forget the header

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way for converting a 64-bit value from LE to BE or vice-versa.

**You can basically apply this method any type, by defining `var_type`:**

```
typedef long long var_type;
```

**Reverse by pointer:**

```
void swapPtr(var_type* x)
{
    char* px = (char*)x;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(var_type)/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = px[i];
        px[i] = px[sizeof(var_type)-1-i];
        px[sizeof(var_type)-1-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

**Reverse by value:**

```
var_type swapVal(var_type x)
{
    var_type y;
    char* px = (char*)&x;
    char* py = (char*)&y;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(var_type); i++)
        py[i] = px[sizeof(var_type)-1-i];
    return y;
}
```

Comment: +1 for nice generic solution.  (Maybe `uint8_t` rather than `char` if one wanted to insure an 8-bit byte swap?)

Comment: Thank you chux. I'm pretty sure that `char` is defined as a single byte in the standard. Doesn't that make the "mapping" between LE and BE accordingly? In other words, the order of bytes in a multi-byte word on an LE processor is opposite to the one on a BE processor, regardless of the size of a single byte... Correct?

Comment: `char` in C is a `byte`, but a `byte` in C in not necessarily 8 bits - it is at _least_ 8 bits.  `uint8_t`, in C, is exactly 8 bits.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576822/sizeof-and-when-a-byte-is-larger-than-8-bits/18576877

Comment: (see above comment also.)  By _definition_  LE and BE have opposite order.  But there are subtle possibilities in this BE/LE business including platforms that use [mixed endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11).  I suspect mixed endian is obsolete today and has a doubtful future of returning.  Note: Some applications need to swap _bit_ order with various serial communications.

Comment: So the size of a single byte is independently defined by the compiler and by the CPU architecture (which always refers to a byte as an 8-bit unit)? Strange... I thought that compilers defining 16-bit bytes would be compilers designated for an underlying architecture of the same "type".

Comment: C maintains an earlier definition of byte which is a collections of bits, 8 certainly being common.  Current literature (CPU manuals) predominately refer to a byte as exactly 8 bits.  "compiler defining 16-bit bytes --> same "type" is certainly true _in general_, but a CPU's native integer bit width and the C code using it is not obliged to match.  Obviously an 8-bit processor can not have a C compliant 8-bit `int` as `int` must range at _least_ -327676 to 32767.  Like-wise, a 64-bit processor could still have C code where the `int` is 32-bits.