# C - fail to convert unsigned char array to double

Tags: c, arrays, char, double, unions

I would like to convert a unsigned char array to double in C. I tried many way to do so but still wrongly converted to 0.00000.

```
union {
   double longtitude;
   unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)];
}u;
unsigned char * receive_buffer = malloc(65536);
int recv = recv(fd,receive_buffer,65536,0); 
// the buffer should has 8 byte value  {40 5c 80 23 8d a3 c2 12}

memcpy(&u.bytes,receive_buffer,sizeof(double));  // copy to char array
for ( int i=8;i>=0;i--){
        u.longtitude = u.bytes[i]; 
    }
printf("%lf",u.longtitude);  // the result is 0.000000 / the expected result should be 114.00217
```

I got the result of '0.000000' from above code that I found from internet. How can I convert the char array to double? What's wrong in above code?

**UPDATE**

I added more specific code above. I have checked the contents of the `receive_buffer` and it contains the value in the above comment. The `u.bytes` correctly gets a value from the buffer via `memcpy`. The `union and for loop` part is the way I found from other similar questions. I tried it, but got result = 0.000000. Sorry about the unclear code posted and problem stated before; I am quite new to C language.

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop.

Comment: Is `buffer` actually something else than what you've shown here? Perhaps a pointer? Here you're passing an uninitialized `unsigned char` value as the source _address_ parameter to `memcpy()` which is of course UB.

Comment: Besides, assuming `sizeof double == 8`, your loop will index past the end of the array (`i = 8`).

Comment: Why a union? The code comments suggest you need to read 8 bytes into a `double`. The `unsigned char buffer;` is size 1, so you can't copy `sizeof(double)` bytes from it.

Comment: Please try this as a self contained test code. Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output

Comment: "I got the result of '0.000000' from above code" is not possible without warnings with a well warning enabled compiler.  Save time and enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @chux I actually run this code in android environment. Perhaps I tried to enable the compiler warnings. Thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: Tip: `printf("%a\n",u.longtitude);` and `printf("%e\n",u.longtitude);` are more informative than `printf("%lf",u.longtitude);`

Comment: Add  `if (recv != 8) exit(-1);` before code proceeds to `memcpy(&u.bytes,receive_buffer,sizeof(double));`  That is more assertive than a comment `the buffer should has 8 byte value`

Comment: @chux: If the value is expected to be meaningful as a longitude, printing it in exponential notation is not very meaningful except for debugging OP's problem.

Comment: @chux, before memcpy, I also printed the recv,  the value of 'receive_buffer' by %x

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `for` loop.

The `memcpy` copies the bytes from the buffer into the `bytes` array of the union. Those are the same bytes used for the `longitude` member, so they are already in place. You do not need the `for` loop to copy those bytes, and it was incorrectly writing the values of the bytes into the **value** of the double rather than into the bytes that represent the value. Also, the loop index was wrong, as it was using 8 in the first iteration, but the bytes in an eight-byte object are indexed 0 to 7.

More than that, in C, you can modify the bytes that repesent an object with either a union or a `memcpy`. You do not need both. After the `recv`, this suffices:

```
double longitude;
memcpy(&longitude, receive_buffer, sizeof longitude);
```

I expect you could even do the `recv` directly into `&longitude`.

Comment: I changed to use memcpy only, it dosen't work, the result is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` loop entirely. I'm not sure what your intent in having it there is, but it undoes (or rather just clobbers) the work you just did.

Comment: But what about `memcpy(&u.bytes,buffer,sizeof(double));` ? The variable `buffer` is 1 byte.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It passes `buffer` to `memcpy`, not `&buffer`. As long as `buffer` is magically initialized by the C implementation to have the address of where the data is in the first 256 bytes of the address space, this is fine. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil but it wasn't. In the original question was `unsigned char buffer;` . The missing `&` is a good spot: but please stop hitting on me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update and the expected value of `114.00217`, the issue is endian-ness. Whatever machine you are getting the value from does not have the same endianess as your machine. So after converting to double, swap endianess.

```
// endian_swap() function taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507710/669576
// I modified to work with double
double endian_swap(double d)
{
    long x = *(long *)&d;
    x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
    x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
    x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;

    return *(double *)&x;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char s[] = {0x40,0x5c,0x80,0x23,0x8d,0xa3,0xc2,0x12};
    double d;
    // Just copy - no union needed
    memcpy(&d, s, sizeof(d));
    // Swap endianess
    d = endian_swap(d);
    printf("%lf\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 114.002170

I don't do a lot of network programming, but I believe the [`ntohl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) function is used for this. However, I don't know if there is a 64-bit version.

---

Update: Also, you can use `htobe64()` (Thanks to @Stargateur):

```
#include <endian.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char s[] = {0x40,0x5c,0x80,0x23,0x8d,0xa3,0xc2,0x12};
    // htobe64() expects a long, so use that first
    long l;
    memcpy(&l, s, sizeof(l));
    l = htobe64(l);
    // Then copy the swapped long bits to a double
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &l, sizeof(d));
    printf("%lf\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```